# Is there a way to upload screenshots with fastlane for 2FA enabled account without user interaction (e.g. via hardware key)?

Tags: ios, macos, screenshot, build-automation, fastlane

Since Apple enforces AppleID accounts to be 2fa enabled and allows only application binary to be uploaded via API with app specific password I can not find a way to get the screenshots uploads fully automated.

I've tried obtaining session token as suggested in [fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#two-step-or-two-factor-auth)

```
fastlane spaceauth -u user@email.com
```

but obviously it also triggers 2FA procedure. Now the question is if this 2FA could be somehow fulfilled with hardware key like Yubico so that session token generation doesn't require any person involvement.

In addition to that it would be great if >100 AppleIDs could be secured with that single hardware key.

Any other solution is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can set up an application specific password for your user. This does not need MFA

Comment: @Paulw11 Accordingly to fastlane docs application specific password works only for app binary. `Note: The application specific password will not work if your action usage does anything else than uploading the binary, e.g. updating any metadata like setting release notes or distributing to testers, etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [API key with the App Store Store Connect APIs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/). You can create API keys through [AppStore Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api)

The username/password authentication capability provided by FastLane was never officially supported by API.  [FastLane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/) documentation recommends the use of API keys over username/password where possible:

> It is **recommended** to use the API Key authentication when you are able to. The benefits include:
>
> - No 2FA needed
> - Better performance
> - Documented API
> - Increased reliability